# Не определяется extension function в Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Начал изучать Kotlin, хочу добавить свою функцию в `LinearLayoutManager`(расширить его, в учебных целях), для того чтобы писать вместо:

```
recycler_packs.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
```

Вот так:

```
recycler_packs.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager.verticalManager(this)
```

Функцию реализовал как по гайдам, но в коде она подсвечивается красным:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
fun LinearLayoutManager.verticalManager(context: Context, reverseLayout: Boolean = false): LinearLayoutManager {
    return LinearLayoutManager(context, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, reverseLayout)
```

Что я делаю не так? Может быть я что - то не так понимаю?

До этого реализовал похожую функцию для `ViewGroup`:

```
fun ViewGroup.inflate(layoutId: Int, attachToRoot: Boolean = false): View {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layoutId, this, attachToRoot)
}
```

Она работает. В чём разница между работающей функцией и моей?

Comment: Вам надо убрать `LinearLayoutManager.` из объявления функции и использовать её также без `LinearLayoutManager.`

Comment: Да, так и сделал. А моя функция видимо работает для экземпляров LinearLayoutManager, а не для класса в целом. Благодарю.

Comment: Да, всё верно - функции подобного рода можно вызывать только на экземплярах класса, они не заменяют собой статические методы из `Java`